# How to do draggable and sortable in table body td using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Draggable is working right now and I want the sortable procedure to work also with these columns. These are simple `div` elements that I want to `sortable` using jQuery UI. Kindly let me know if there is anything wrong with the code below.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>File A</td>
            <td><span id="draggable" class="label label-default ui-widget-content filediv"> </span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span id="draggable1" class="label label-default ui-widget-content filediv"> </span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>File B</td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span id="draggable2" class="label label-success ui-widget-content filediv"> </span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
   $( function() {
   $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
   $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
   $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
  } );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you specify which columns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This does not include what you have tried for `sortable`. Your question does not seem complete. Please include any errors you see in console and the code you have tried. What is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took some guesses, but I think you want to Drag and Drop, not Sort.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/g21dso7e/2/

**CSS**

```
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-condensed {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table tr {
  padding: 0.2em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table tr td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  min-width: 1.5em;
  min-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
}

.table tr td span.label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: 0.2em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".label").draggable();
  $(".table tbody tr td").droppable({
    accept: ".label",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
      ui.draggable.appendTo($(this)).css({
        top: "0.4em",
        left: "0.2em"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Since you have a class of `label` for each, I would use this as a single selector. When draggable is used in conjunction with droppable, you can then append the dropped item to an element. Draggable simply adjusts it's position but does not change it's place in the DOM.

When the item is dropped on a table cell, the `drop` callback does the work for us. The CSS helps drop the item into the right position in the cell.

Comment: i want the both feature in table columns.sortable is must

Comment: So you wish to sort the columns?